# How to persist changes made in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I'm using `Card` from `react-native-elements` and I got rid of the

```
{image && ..... <BackgroundImage .....
```

part because I wanted to add a placeholder image (activity indicator) before the image was downloaded, so that I dont just see a blank area before the image fades in.

Anyway, I replaced that part with another component and it just hit me -- my `.gitignore` ignores `/node_modules`. If I were to make such changes as I did to the `Card` and then buy a new computer and clone my repo, running `npm install` will not give me the npm modules with my changes.

How can I get around this? I don't want to push my whole node_modules directory. Also, I thought about just making my own component based on `Card`, but it has way too many dependencies and imports that I don't want to get into resolving and copying over to my project as well if I don't have to.

Comment: fork that library on github, make the changes. Use it on package json instead of npm version

Comment: or you can try exploring this patching module https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package#benefits-of-patching-over-forking

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend https://github.com/ds300/patch-package here; makes patches and apply them consistently to things in node_modules. Often useful for fixes that were never pushed to certain versions of packages.

Comment: That’s the same package that’s in the comment from a year ago, isn’t it?

Answer (score 1):

You should never make changes to node_modules due to the reason you have described, Your changes are just temporary, and if you decide to update the dependency your changes will be lost.

Depending on your reason for changing the code, you can do other things:

- If this is a feature, you can request it to make them, or open a pull request for them

  - If its a bug, open a bug for them, or again make a pull request it to solve it

If you want to make changes that persist then you have to make your own library that is based on theirs (Assuming their license allowing you yo do so), This is a really bad option, you lose all the automatic updates, and bug fixes.

What you should do is what you suggested, is that you should build a wrapper component over their component, and in that case you are not adding any new dependencies (the dependencies they use will be there anyway, unless you decide to build the component from the scratch using their dependencies, in this case this is not a Wrapper component but a whole new component, avoid this option if you can just wrap their component to achieve what you want)

Answer (score 1):

**We have solve this issue by creating update_note_modules.sh(shell executables) file and run this file after every npm/yarn install**

**Step 1:  Save copy of your code from node_modules to your main application folder . We have created "core" folder and save copy there**

[image]

**Step 2 : Create update_note_modules.sh file**

[image]

File Code

```
echo "Updating react-native-dropdownalert"
cp core/react-native-dropdownalert/DropdownAlert.js node_modules/react-native-dropdownalert/DropdownAlert.js

echo "node_modules updated"
```

**Note: Path will change according to your project**

**Step 3: Run update_note_modules.sh after every npm/yarn install**

**Just paste the path of file in terminal and hit enter to execute file**

```
/path to file/update_note_modules.sh
```

Comment: That may work sometimes, but it’s very, very brittle—it makes a lot of assumptions. This is not the best approach.